в CryEngine 5.7.1 Navigation area не сохраняется
в CryEngine 5.7.1 Navigation area запускается, но при перезагрузке движка, не сохраняется и пишет предупреждение : 21:17:41 AI: Navigation system couldn't find NavMesh triangle at path start point (113.55, 135.841949, 31.999756) for agent 'Human-4'. Все сохранения мною выполняются. Но при новом запуске игры, выдается это предупреждение и нужно выполнить переустановку Navmesh, после чего все опять прекрасно работает, но до перезагрузки. Что это: где-то нужно еще что-то запустить или это - баг?

В чем ваш вопрос? Вам нужен перевод предупреждения? Системе навигации, не удалось найти треугольник NavMesh в начальной точке пути (координаты), для агента человек-4

Суть в том, что Navigation area для AI устанавливается и все работает. Все сохранения мною выполняются. Но при новом запуске игры, выдается это предупреждение и нужно выполнить переустановку навмеша, после чего все опять прекрасно работает. Что это: где-то нужно еще что-то запустить или баг?
